# Suppose $2^n$ and $5^n$ start with the same digit $d$, for some $n\ge 1$.Find $d$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $2^n$ and $5^n$ start with the same digit $d$, for some $n\ge 1$.Find $d$.
My work:
I can manually see that for $n=5$, $2^5$ and $5^5$ start with same digit $3$, but I could do that as $n$ was small. But, how would I do it if I could not find such $n$ easily. Please help with a mathematical technique and not a manual one.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is a "mathematical technique" for these things.

Comment: So, you mean I need to check it manually, until I find $n$?

Comment: Seems to me so, @Hawk...but wait a little: perhaps someone else comes up with something.

Comment: @DonAntonio. Ok

Comment: Here is some basic idea to start with: find a sequence of *last digit* of $2^n$ and a sequence for *last digit* of $5^n$, if you're lucky, maybe there is a some pattern, but I doubt about that.

Comment: @SalechAlhasov, how could that possibly help if we **have** to go by the *first* digit?!

Comment: @DonAntonio.That is what I was about to post!I was wondering too!

Comment: The fact that $10^n$ starts with $d^2$ plus some carry seems to rule out $d > 3$...

Comment: @fkraiem.I could not understand what you said!

Comment: @Hawk, Hi Hawk, I saw you cancelled the acceptance? Mind letting me know the reason please?

Comment: Yes, I showed the solution to a friend of mine, but he identified a problem in the solution given by you. For e.g., if both $2^n$ and $5^n$ start with 1,then according to your logic we get a error. Rather, he showed me a perfect solution where he has proved that the numbers have no other way but to start with 3. I can post the solution if you want to see.

Comment: @Hawk, the only way 1xxx * 1xxx =10^n is all the x are zeros, but it is not possible for any 2^n or 5^n. As a result, the first digit cannot be 1.

Comment: Yes, but it it too arguable approach...but the one I got is not so. It directly gives you that $d$ can be none other than 3.

Answer (score 4):

Are you just looking for such $d$, or you need the $n$ as well?  $2^n \times 5^n = 10^n$. Only two numbers with the same first digit $3$ can get a $10^n$ product. $d$ can only be $3$.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for $n$. But, can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: @Hawk, two numbers with the same starting digits, and their product is 10^n, I don't think other possibilities except 3XX * 3XXXX... something like that

Comment: Works for $n=5, 15, 78, 88, 98, 108, 118, 181, 191, 201, 211, 274, 284, 294, 304, 367, 377, 387, 397, 407, 470, 480, 490, 500...$

Comment: For completeness, you need to rule out $100\ldots \times 100 \ldots$, but that's obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution for $d$ is $3$, because $10^n$ must carry $1$ as first digit, and as we are multiplying basically two numbers so the first digit cannot carry $>1$ from second digit. $3*3=9$, $7*7=49$. But the second one will give $5$ as first digit if it carries $1$,so only possible is $3$.If we see the case of carrying $0$ from second digit then $1*1=1$ but then the other digits of the product cannot be $0$ if $2^n$ & $5^n$ both starts with 1. So only possible $d=3$, hence proved.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).